# Ignore external links in go web crawler

Tags: go, web-crawler, url-parsing

I'm really new to go, and I'm playing with it at the moment by building a simple web crawler following this tutorial: https://jdanger.com/build-a-web-crawler-in-go.html

It's broken down really nicely, but I want to put something in place so that the only links which are enqueued are part of the main domain, and not external.

So let's say I'm crawling https://www.mywebsite.com, I only want to include things like https://www.mywebsite.com/about-us or https://www.mywebsite.com/contact - I don't want subdomains, such as https://subdomain.mywebsite.com or external links found like https://www.facebook.com as I do not want the crawler to fall into a black hole.

Looking at the code, I *think* I need to make the change to this function which fixes relative links:

```
func fixUrl(href, base string) (string) {  // given a relative link and the page on
  uri, err := url.Parse(href)              // which it's found we can parse them
  if err != nil {                          // both and use the url package's
    return ""                              // ResolveReference function to figure
  }                                        // out where the link really points.
  baseUrl, err := url.Parse(base)          // If it's not a relative link this
  if err != nil {                          // is a no-op.
    return ""
  }
  uri = baseUrl.ResolveReference(uri)
  return uri.String()                      // We work with parsed url objects in this
}                                          // func but we return a plain string.
```

However I'm not 100% sure how to do that, I'm assuming some sort of if/else or further parsing is required.

Any tips would be hugely appreciated for my learning

Answer (score 1):

I quickly read the jdanger tutorial and ran the complete example. No doubt there are a few ways to accomplish what you want to do, but here's my take.

You basically want to **not** enqueue any URL whose domain doesn't match some specified domain, presumably provided as a command line arg. The example uses the `fixUrl()` function to construct full absolute URLs and also to signal invalid URLs (by returning `""`). In this function, it relies on the `net/url` package for parsing and such, and specifically on the [`URL` data type](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL). `URL` is a `struct` with this definition:

```golang
type URL struct {
    Scheme      string
    Opaque      string    // encoded opaque data
    User        *Userinfo // username and password information
    Host        string    // host or host:port
    Path        string    // path (relative paths may omit leading slash)
    RawPath     string    // encoded path hint (see EscapedPath method); added in Go 1.5
    ForceQuery  bool      // append a query ('?') even if RawQuery is empty; added in Go 1.7
    RawQuery    string    // encoded query values, without '?'
    Fragment    string    // fragment for references, without '#'
    RawFragment string    // encoded fragment hint (see EscapedFragment method); added in Go 1.15
}
```

The one to take note of is `Host`. `Host` is the 'whatever.com' part of an URL, including subdomains, and the port (see [this wikipedia article for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)). Further reading the documentation, there is a method `Hostname()` which will strip the port, if present.

So, although you *could* add domain filtering to `fixUrl()`, a better design, in my opinion, would be to 'fix' the URL first, then do an addition check on the result to see its `Host` matches the desired domain. If it does **not** match, do not enqueue the URL and continue to the next item in the queue.

So, basically I think you are on the right track. I haven't included a code example to encourage you to work it out yourself, though I did add your feature to my local copy of the tutorial's program.